# T-SQL. Триггер, меняющий вставляемые значения

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE Rezultat_kontrol_meropriyatiya
( 
    ID_rezultata         integer IDENTITY ( 1,1 ) ,
    ID_prepodavatelya    integer  NOT NULL ,
    ID_disciplini        integer  NOT NULL ,
    ID_formi_kontrolya   integer  NOT NULL ,
    ID_studenta          integer  NOT NULL ,
    Ocenka               integer  NULL ,
    Data                 datetime  NOT NULL 
);
```

В нее вставляется строка:

```
INSERT INTO Rezultat_kontrol_meropriyatiya VALUES (1,1,1,1,1,'хор','01,01,2001')
```

Создаю триггер:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.translateScore ON dbo.Rezultat_kontrol_meropriyatiya FOR INSERT, UPDATE AS 
BEGIN
    PRINT ('TRIGGER!!!')
    SELECT * FROM inserted;
END;
```

Вопрос в том, как сделать триггер, который заменит строку `'хор'` на `4`?
Сейчас при вызове `INSERT-а` выводит ошибку преобразования строки в `INT`. Я хочу чтобы мой триггер заменил значение на INT в зависимости от строки ДО преобразования типов

Comment: триггер срабатывает только если запись уже пытается вставляться, а следовательно все преобразования типов уже произошли. Но вы можете сделать view на таблицу с нужным типом данным нужного столбца и создать триггер на эту view, который преобразует и запишет данные в таблицу. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/def01zh2.aspx

Comment: Нужно использовать `INSTEAD` триггер. И в нем брать значения из inserted, преобразовывать в то, что нужно и вставлять.